# Why flowjs doesn't throw error on empty array when array must be of a type?

Tags: flowtype

Can't understand why the following code pass flow check:

```
type Foo = "A" | "B" | "C"

const myFoo: Array<Foo> = []
```

Isn't `Array<Foo>` enforcing the array to have some `Foo` type?

I'm a bit confused.

Flow repl: https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAiAgqqAfNAhLXVAYVQCgyBjOAOwGdgoBbEeOALinQCduBDEAB42APmRQA2gF0yQA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `Array<Foo>` means that all elements in the array must have type `Foo`. This is true for the empty array `[]`: all elements in this array have type `Foo`. It just so happens that there are no elements in the array. Flow will enforce that all elements added to the array will be of type `Foo`.